# Wanted To re-render table rows when state in redux changed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I Used redux action to delete the first rows of table when click Good btn

**Reducer of LineMange.js**

```js
const LineManage = (state = Initstate, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'AddP':
      console.log(state.Products);
      return {};
    case 'RemP':
      state.data.splice(0, 1);
      console.log(state.data);
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        data: state.data
      });
    default:
      console.log(state.data);
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Pannel.jsx**

```js
class Pannel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.data,
      Img:
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/No_image_3x4.svg/1200px-No_image_3x4.svg.png', // default Value
      Sheet: {
        in_or: 0,
        Hr_plan: 0,
        Inactual: 0,
        NG: 0,
        DIFF: 0,
        T_plan: 0,
        T_Actual: 0,
        T_DIFF: 0,
        OEEE: 0,
        OA: 0,
        NG_T: 0,
        BAL: 0
      } // default value
    };
    const { RemP } = this.props;
    this.RemP = RemP.bind(this);
    this.handleScanner = this.handleScanner.bind(this);
    this.codevalue = '';
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keypress', this.handleScanner);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    console.warn('update ' + nextProps);
    return true;
  }

  handleScanner(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      alert(this.codevalue);
    } else {
      this.codevalue += e.key;
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.warn('render');
    return (
      <>
        <Container fluid="true">
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Psheet />
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row style={{ marginTop: '15px' }}>
            <Col lg={6} md={6}>
              <div className="frame">
                <Container>
                  <h2 className="Header">Sheet</h2>
                  <div className="TableControl">
                    <Table striped bordered hover>
                      <thead>
                        <th className="text-center p-0">Kaban No.</th>
                        <th className="text-center p-0">Part No.</th>
                        <th className="text-center p-0">Part Name</th>
                        <th className="text-center p-0">Qty's per Kaban</th>
                        <th className="text-center p-0">Status</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {this.state.data.map((data, index) => {
                          const { Name, Unit, Status } = data.info;
                          return (
                            <tr value={data.ID}>
                              <td>{index + 1}</td>
                              <td>{data.ID}</td>
                              <td>{Name}</td>
                              <td>{Unit}</td>
                              <td>{Status}</td>
                            </tr>
                          );
                        })}
                      </tbody>
                    </Table>
                  </div>
                  <hr />
                  <Row>
                    <Col>
                      <Button
                        onClick={this.RemP}
                        style={{ marginRight: ' 20px' }}
                        variant="success"
                        size="lg"
                      >
                        Good
                      </Button>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                      <Button
                        style={{ marginRight: ' 20px' }}
                        variant="danger"
                        size="lg"
                      >
                        No Good
                      </Button>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <hr />
                </Container>
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col style={{ marginTop: '20px' }} lg={6} md={6}>
              <div className="frame">
                <Qp imgsr={this.state.data[0].info.Img_src} />
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    RemP: () => dispatch(RemP())
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
  return {
    data: state.LineManage.data
  };
};

const Pan = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Pannel);
export default Pan;
```

the state in the redux is change but the component don't re-render and not even trigger shouldcomponentupdate() even if I tried to pass the props directly to the render() but the other page that count the length of data in the reducer is function just fine, So if I did anything wrong please tell me, I really new to react-redux

Comment: When you initialize state in constructor, `data` state is filled only once and will not be filled again when props change from Redux. Try using `this.props.data` instead of `this.state.data` in your JSX. You don't need it in state at all. If you need `data` to be in state, a lifecycle hook may be used to update state.

Comment: @IOOIIIO  I tried cut I Still not re-render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've assigned `this.props.data` to `state.data` on `constructor`. The `state.data` will not be changed when `this.props.data` is changed.

So you should use props data directly in `render()` to reflect store change immediately.

```
this.props.data.map((data,index) => {
  // ...
})
```

**UPDATE**

Try to change your reducer for `RemP` like below.

```
case 'RemP':
  return {
    ...state,
    data: state.data.slice(1, state.data.length)
  }
```

Comment: It's Work Thank you so much, but can you explain why ? because I really have no idea.

Comment: When you use `Object.assign` you're assigning like {data: state.data} which means just assigning array object reference. This will not reflect the view side. You should assign completely new array object. So you can also change your code to `{
        data: [...state.data]
      }` and this will work as well.

Comment: Ok I get it now, Thank you @baymax

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `this.props.data` instead of `this.state.data`.

```
    <tbody>
       {this.props.data.map((data,index) => {
         //...
       })}
    </tbody>
```

2. Or you can use static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) react lifecycle.

```
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
      this.state.data = props.data;
    }
```